# how to change static method in php outside class

Tags: php, oop, static-methods

We can change the static variable value of a class from outside, thats the advantage of static variables but how do we change static method from outside ?

```
<?php

class A
{
   static $static_var = 0;   

   static function test(){
      return 'i want to change inside this test method';
   }
}
echo A::$static_var; // outputs 0

++A::$static_var;

echo A::$static_var; // ouputs 1

// Now how do we do something to change the static test method body? is it possible ?
like

A::test() = function(){ /* this is wrong */} 

}
```

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Being able to change a variable from outside the class is nothing to do with being static, it's all about being public

Comment: As for being able to change a variable..... that's what ___variable___ is all about.... but functions are not variables, and there should be no reason to change a function definition dynamically

Comment: If you need "dynamic" methods, then look to [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead

Comment: @MarkBaker i think we cannot change public variable value of a class from outside. Only static variables can be changed and the class will continue to hold the changed static value in that particular lines of code. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: when we extend the class A with child class B and redeclare test method to overwrite parents class then its working. i guess without extending it wont work.

Comment: both instance and static variables can be changed from outside the class or instance if they are public... the difference is that you don't need an instance of a class to change a static variable, but an instance variable can only be changed against an instance

Answer (score 3):

As @Mark Baker said, you can only change variable...
But there is a way to declare variable as callable, you can use anonymous function.

here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
class A
{
   public static $method;
}

A::$method = function() { 
    echo 'A'; 
};

call_user_func(A::$method);
// OR
$method = A::$method;
$method();
```

Comment: Here you are assigning a function to a variable and calling that variable functions, i am curious to know can we change the body of already declared static method from outside of the class. If it is possible to change static variable value why not method body ?